# Failed update list value in a for-loop but succeed in list with object value

Tags: java, list, for-loop, reference, updates

I tried to run a for-loop and update a double value in a list , and I found that I failed.
I search on the web and I know that when getting double value by **List#get(i)** method is simply get a **copy** of the value, such that will not update a value in a list, just like the code below.

```
        List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list1.add(10.0);
        for(int i = 0; i < list1.size() ; i++){
            Double value = list1.get(i);
            value = value/100;
            System.out.println(list1.get(i));
        }

        //Result 10.0
```

the only way is use the **List#set(i, value)** method.

Now I add a Test class

```
class Test{
    Double value;

    public Test(Double value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and do the similar thing with Test class

```
        List<Test> list2 = new ArrayList<Test>();
        Test test = new Test(10.0);
        list2.add(test1);

        for(int i = 0; i < list2.size() ; i++){
             Test test = list2.get(i);
             test.value = test.value / 100;
             System.out.println(test.value);
        }

        //Result 0.1
```

My question is : Why the value in a list will update. Isn't the test object in a for loop still a **copy** of the original one ? Is it because of primitive data type or reference difference?

Comment: `Isn't the test object in a for loop still a copy of the original one?` - No, what's being returned by `list2.get(i)` in this case is a reference to the original `Test` object.

Comment: you correct my wrong idea! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between immutable objects (such as Float and String) and mutable objects (such as your `Test` class).

Mutable objects can be updated. The list contains a reference to the object. When you change the content of that object, the list still refers to the same object, which is now changed.

Comment: thanks for your help, you teach me the immutable and mutable concept clearly!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the issue here is that the primitive wrapper types are immutable.

```
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
list1.add(10.0);
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size() ; i++){
  Double value = list1.get(i);
  value = value/100;                      // <-- creates a new value!
  System.out.println(list1.get(i));
}
```

You could use the shorter,

```
List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
list1.add(10.0);
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size() ; i++){
  list1.set(i, list1.get(i) / 10);
  System.out.println(list1.get(i));
}
```

Comment: great, thanks for your help, I know this method, but I totally forget the immutable and mutable thing.